# How to deal with outdated answers to an old question?

Tags: discussion, old-questions, outdated-information

The answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10381084/custom-http-method-with-nodejs-http-server) is modifying a piece of code in an older version of NodeJS, which was working for the OP. But with the latest version of NodeJS files, the accepted answer is no longer relevant.

How can I get answers for the latest versions? Post a new/similar question? But it would be outdated again in future.

Comment: I placed a bounty on the question to encourage new answers. I don't know anything about the technology though so I'll need help deciding who to give it to (either through feedback or community votes)

Comment: Is there a way to sort the answers by date * votes or something smarter? Sometimes a question can get several outdated answers and the newest answer might have 0 or 1 vote and ranked last on the answer list -_- |||

Comment: Related: ["This is not a duplicate of this question because the accepted answer is wrong."](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/381607/this-is-not-a-duplicate-of-this-question-because-the-accepted-answer-is-wrong)