# 'This is not a duplicate of this question because the accepted answer is wrong'

Tags: discussion, questions, duplicate-questions, accepted-answer

I am referring to [this specific question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39110801/path-join-vs-path-resolve-with-dirname/39111164), particularly the last line that the author wrote:

> This is not a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35048686/difference-between-path-resolve-and-path-join-invocation) because the accepted answer is wrong.

I am puzzled.

I can't see why the content of *answers* would have an influence on the duplicity of the *question*. The questions are almost indiscernible from one another. As far as I understood, the *stack-overflow-way* of dealing with wrong answers is to downvote it, explain why it's wrong in the comment, and place a bounty on the question so as to attract new answers.

On the other hand, I do understand that that this method has flaws, and making a new question with a non-duplicate disclaimer (as the OP did) will attract fresher answers with the clear warning that the other accepted answer might be incorrect.

I just passed the 2k bar and the OP has more reputation on Stack Overflow than I do, but I don't fully agree with what they did there.

Am I missing something? In which situations is it acceptable to use such a non-duplicate disclaimer? Should I flag one of the two similar questions as duplicate, and, if so, which one?

Comment: It mainly lacks an explanation _why_ the answer on the duplicate doesn't apply to his situation. A question can only be marked as a duplicate if the target has an answer. At the time of posting, the linked question only contained a single invalid answer, that since has been deleted. Still, this behavior is questionable, but the question is also slightly different because of different things.

Comment: The author can use whatever "duplicate disclaimer" they want. That doesn't meant the question is or isn't a duplicate.

Comment: @yivi yes it's in the question *I just passed the 2k bar and Estus is a Stack Overflow OG compared to me, but still, I don't fully agree with what he did there.*

Comment: Eh... A 70K rep person is still just a person. Also, if you search far back enough, I'm sure even Jon Skeet will have questionable questions or answers. Discussing the person is not needed and bad form on meta

Comment: @yivi edited to *Estus has more experience on this forum than me*

Comment: @yivi: Without expanding what "OG" stands for, its use is supposed to refer to early adopters or the very, very first members of a site. As Gimby said though, its use here is wrong because the 4 years that user has been here isn't even half the age of the site.

Comment: The question is from three years ago. Pretty sure they had less experience back then.

Comment: @ErikA true! But you'll likely agree on the fact than the higher the reputation, the more likely is the person to ask good questions

Comment: @NinoFiliu I would *strongly* disagree with that statement.

Comment: @Servy how come?

Comment: This is what comes from focusing on the user instead of the post. Now we are discussing users in general instead of the main point of your question.

Comment: @NinoFiliu: no, reputation has nothing to do with it.

Comment: The "stack-overflow-way" of dealing with wrong answers is essentially useless for doing anything about answers upvoted as highly as that one. I don't know enough about Node to tell whether that answer is any good from a cursory glance, but if it's wrong, downvoting it will do basically nothing.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

> In which situations is it acceptable to use such a non-duplicate disclaimer?

The author of a question can add disclaimers to their question to explain why their question is not a duplicate to another question (be it that it was flagged/voted as dupe to it, or as general proof of the user doing their due dilligence and research).

But that disclaimer should actually **explain** why the other question is not a duplicate, and how answers to the potential duplicate target do not answer their own question.

A blanket statement *"it's not a duplicate from X"*, or even one like the specific one you are quoting, are simply not enough.

And as you point, disagreement with the content or quality of the answers in the other question is not a good reason to post a duplicate.

> Should I flag one of the two similar questions as duplicate, and, if so, which one?

If you are convinced a question is a duplicate from another, do flag it. Which one to flag would depend mostly on the relative quality of the answers on each question.

Heed disclaimers only if you believe they do a good job at explaining why the questions are not dupes. If they do not do that, or simply fail to convince you, follow your own judgement and experience.

> I just passed the 2k bar and the OP has more reputation on Stack Overflow than I do, but I don't fully agree with what they did there

Do not pay too much attention to reputation. No matter the reputation a user has, they can err. You are not expected to agree with other users just because they have more Internet points than you.

Comment: Unfortunately most common explanation is roughly "This is not a duplicate of any question on your stupid site, just give me answer" (obviously without any links or even hint of details)… So one with at least link to the duplicate is already way above average...

Comment: This is an excellent answer.  I know because I'm guilty of not providing more info in my *duplicate disclaimer* in [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54675647/8239061). After about 2 weeks of documentation reading, Google & SO searches, and lots of failed coding attempts, I posted [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54675647/8239061) with a [CVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) but should have provided details on why the linked posts didn't help me or what parts I didn't understand.

Comment: This answer is pretty old, but (for that specific question pair) the questions are fixed and the answer in both are correct now.

Answer (score 6):

> I can't see why the content of *answers* would have an influence on the duplicity of the *question*.

You are somewhat misunderstanding how the "duplicate" feature works. It is not the *question* that is a duplicate of another *question*, it is the ***answer***, that (if written) would be a duplicate of an *answer* already written for another question.

Read the text that is presented for a "duplicate":

> **This question already has answers here:**
> *<link to question here>* (*X* answers)

The question may not be a duplicate, but it is similar enough that the *answer* is the same.

Of course, if the question really is a duplicate, the answers would be the same, so you would for sure use the duplicate feature for that. However, note that the system won't allow you link to a "duplicate question" that doesn't have any up-voted answers. This highlights the fact that it is the *answers* of the question that is important, not the question itself.

Also note that it is not necessarily the *accepted* answer that is being referred to. Sometimes the wrong, or less optimal, answer is accepted by the questioner, but another answer is much better and more on point. This is sometimes seen by the accepted answer having a low (sometimes negative) vote score, and a second answer having a much higher vote score.